# AngularJS turns my single quotes into &#39;

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using ng-bind-html in two places.

In one of the places I just use it like this:

```
<p class="message-preview" ng-bind-html="message.message"></p>
```

And the output there is: `What's up?`

In another place I run a filter called linky which comes with Angular that turns urls into clickable urls:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/filter/linky

I use it here:

```
<p class="message" ng-bind-html="message.message | linky:'_blank'"></p>
```

But now the output is `What&#39;s up?`

I have included ngSanitize:

```
angular
    .module('app', [
        'ui.router',
        'ngMessages',
        'ngSanitize',
        'vcRecaptcha',
        'ngFileUpload',
        'angularModalService',
        'ngImgCrop'
    ]);
```

And the message is sanitized on the server side before it is saved into the database.

What should I do to fix this issue?

EDIT:

The message is saved as this in the database: `What&#39;s up?`

Comment: Can you create a plnkr for your code using http://plnkr.co/ ?

Comment: if you turned this variable into a clickable url, why wouldn't angular convert the `'` into `&#39;`?  the latter is valid in a URI, the former is not.

Comment: Actually it does not convert the ' into &#39; I was wrong. It is already saved as &#39; in the database. I expected it to display &#39; as '. ng-bind-html displays &#39; as ', but when I filter with linky, it shows &#39; as &#39;